# Run a program and return value libreoffice calc

Tags: c, libreoffice

I wrote an algorithm in c that takes input of double precision numbers and returns a double. I would like to use this in libreoffice calc. I tried making a macro function using shell but it only gives back 0. How do I write the macro so it gives back the number that the c program returns. Also how do I make it so I can input the three numbers from a cell into the c program?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you have the C program write the results to a text file, and then have the macro read the text file?  And, input numbers (put into the macro by making the macro a "Function" and then calling it from the cell by `=FunctionName(Input1,Input2,Input3)`) should be able to be passed in the macro line that calls the shell function.

Comment: 1) Too broad. Show what you have and ask about a **specific** problem. 2) C and C++ are **different** languages. Don't add tags for unrelated languages and 3) Read tag-descriptions before adding them.

Answer (score 3):

Using a shell interface does not seem workable here, because as you mentioned, it will just return 0 for success.  Instead, I can think of two ways to do this.

The first is to create a [Calc add-in](http://www.openoffice.org/sc/addin_howto.html).  You can specify the number of arguments (3 in your case) in the IDL file.  This would mean that there is no need for any OpenOffice Basic code -- everything can be done in C++.  It is a rather clean solution.  There are quite a few configuration files needed though, and it may initially be more difficult than what is described below.

The second is to dynamically load the DLL and call the function.  I have had success using [PyUNO](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) with the ctypes library, but it can be done in OpenOffice Basic as well.

See also:

- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=45675
- http://sheepdogguides.com/fdb/opof6dll.htm